# R Create Column as Running Average of Another Column

Tags: r, performance

I want to create a column in R that is simply the average of all previous values of another column.   For Example:

```
D
    X
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10 10
```

I would like D$Y to be the prior average of D$X that is, D$Y is the average of all previous observations of D$X.  I know how to do this using a for loop moving through every row, but is there a more efficient manner?

I have a large dataset and hardware not up to that task!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: Do you mean `dput`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson no, i mean `reproduce(.)`  ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: Then you'd have to do `source("https://github.com/rsaporta/pubR/blob/gitbranch/reproduce.R")` first (should mention that to the OP :-))

Comment: I did say "Instructions are here"  where the link to source is located.  The function is also great for bug reports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate cumulative means of a vector like this:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-sample(20)
x
## [1]  6 15  8 16 17  1 18 12  7 20 10  5 11  9 19 13 14  4  3  2
xmeans<-cumsum(x)/1:length(x)
xmeans
## [1]  6.000000 10.500000  9.666667 11.250000 12.400000 10.500000 11.571429
## [8] 11.625000 11.111111 12.000000 11.818182 11.250000 11.230769 11.071429
## [15] 11.600000 11.687500 11.823529 11.388889 10.947368 10.500000
```

So `D$Y<-cumsum(D$X)/1:nrow(D)` should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is working very well, certainly blowing away looping through every row :)

Comment: What about missing data?

Comment: @Thomas Good question.  I can't think of a way to do it in one line, but something like `nax<-is.na(x); x[nax]<-0; cumsum(x)/cumsum(!nax)` should work.